# llamar un metodo privado desde otra clase en android

Tags: android, clase, método

Tengo la siguiente clase preguntas:

```
public class preguntas extends AppCompatActivity{

public static MediaPlayer preguntas15;
Button respuestabtn;
public static int MILISEGUNDOS_ESPERA = 3000;
public  static Button a, b, c, d, cincuentacincuenta, retirarse;
ImageButton cerrar, llamada,publico;
public static TextView preguntas, acumulado;
String quizbase[][];
public static String respuestacorrecta;
private int respuestacorrectacontador = 0;
public int quizcontador;
static final private int CONTADORQUIZ = 15;
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray1 = new  ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray2 = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray3 = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray4 = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray5 = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray6 = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray7 = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray8 = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray9 = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray10 = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray11 = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray12 = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray13 = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray14 = new ArrayList<>();
 public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray15 = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_preguntas);
    MainActivity.cancioninicio.stop();
    //MainActivity.preguntas915= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.preguntas915);
    MainActivity.preguntas915.setLooping(true);
    MainActivity.preguntas915.start();
    quizcontador=1;
    r = new Random();
    cerrar =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.cerrar);
    publico =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.publico);
    cerrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    llamada =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.llamada);
    retirarse =(Button)findViewById(R.id.retirarse);
    cincuentacincuenta= (Button)findViewById(R.id.cincuentacincuenta);
    a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
    c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.c);
    d = (Button) findViewById(R.id.d);
   publico.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity.comodin.start();
            Intent i = new Intent(preguntas.this,publico.class);
            startActivity(i);
            publico.setEnabled(false);

        }
    });
    cincuentacincuenta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity.comodin.start();
            chequearrespuestacincuenta();
            cincuentacincuenta.setEnabled(false);

        }
    });
    llamada.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            llamada.setEnabled(false);
            MainActivity.comodin.start();
            Intent i = new Intent(preguntas.this,Llamada.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    retirarse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity.aplausos.start();
            String dato=acumulado.getText().toString();
            Intent i = new Intent(preguntas.this,acumuladoganado.class);
            i.putExtra("DATO",dato);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            b.setEnabled(false);
            c.setEnabled(false);
            d.setEnabled(false);
            MainActivity.tononaranja.start();
            a.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.millonariobotonesnaranja)) ;
            esperar(MILISEGUNDOS_ESPERA);

        }
    });
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            a.setEnabled(false);
            c.setEnabled(false);
            d.setEnabled(false);
            MainActivity.tononaranja.start();
            b.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.millonariobotonesnaranja)) ;
            esperarb(MILISEGUNDOS_ESPERA);

        }
    });
    c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            b.setEnabled(false);
            a.setEnabled(false);
            d.setEnabled(false);
            MainActivity.tononaranja.start();
            c.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.millonariobotonesnaranja)) ;
            esperarc(MILISEGUNDOS_ESPERA);

        }
    });
    d.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            b.setEnabled(false);
            c.setEnabled(false);
            a.setEnabled(false);
            MainActivity.tononaranja.start();
            d.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.millonariobotonesnaranja)) ;
            esperard(MILISEGUNDOS_ESPERA);

        }
    });
    preguntas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.preguntas);
    acumulado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.acumulado);
    acumulado.setText("0.0$");


        showNextQuiz();







   }
   public void esperar(int milisegundos) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            chequearrespuesta(a);
        }
    }, milisegundos);
  }
  public void esperarb(int milisegundos) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            chequearrespuesta(b);
        }
    }, milisegundos);
  }
  public void esperarc(int milisegundos) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            chequearrespuesta(c);
        }
    }, milisegundos);
 }
public void esperard(int milisegundos) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            chequearrespuesta(d);
        }
    }, milisegundos);
}
public void avanzar(int milisegundos) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int contador=0  ;
            String dato=Integer.toString(contador);
            Intent i=new Intent(preguntas.this, Transicion.class);
            i.putExtra("DATO",dato);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }, milisegundos);
 }
  public  void showNextQuiz () {

    if (quizcontador == 1) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNum = random.nextInt(quizArray1.size());
        ArrayList<String> quiz = quizArray1.get(randomNum);
        preguntas.setText(quiz.get(0));
        respuestacorrecta = quiz.get(1);
        quiz.remove(0);
        Collections.shuffle(quiz);
        a.setEnabled(true);
        b.setEnabled(true);
        c.setEnabled(true);
        a.setText("A. "+quiz.get(0));
        SpannableString sa = new SpannableString(a.getText().toString());
        ForegroundColorSpan fa = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
        sa.setSpan(fa,0,2, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        a.setText(sa);
        b.setText("B. "+quiz.get(1));
        SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(b.getText().toString());
        ForegroundColorSpan fb = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
        sb.setSpan(fb,0,2, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        b.setText(sb);
        c.setText("C. "+quiz.get(2));
        SpannableString sc = new SpannableString(c.getText().toString());
        ForegroundColorSpan fc = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
        sc.setSpan(fc,0,2, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        c.setText(sc);
        d.setText("D. "+quiz.get(3));
        SpannableString sd = new SpannableString(d.getText().toString());
        ForegroundColorSpan fd = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
        sd.setSpan(fd,0,2, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        d.setText(sd);
        quizArray1.remove(randomNum);
       }

  }


  public void chequearrespuestacincuenta () {

    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNum = random.nextInt(3);
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "numero:" + randomNum, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
    String btntextoa = a.getText().toString();
    String btntextob = b.getText().toString();
    String btntextoc = c.getText().toString();
    String btntextod = d.getText().toString();
    String sSubCadena = btntextoa.substring(3, btntextoa.length());
    String pSubCadena = btntextob.substring(3, btntextob.length());
    String tSubCadena = btntextoc.substring(3, btntextoc.length());
    String rSubCadena = btntextod.substring(3, btntextod.length());



    if (randomNum == 0) {

        if(sSubCadena.equals(respuestacorrecta) || pSubCadena.equals(respuestacorrecta) ) {

            c.setEnabled(false);
            d.setEnabled(false);
            c.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            d.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    } else if (tSubCadena.equals(respuestacorrecta)) {

        b.setEnabled(false);
        d.setEnabled(false);
        b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        d.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else if (rSubCadena.equals(respuestacorrecta)) {
        b.setEnabled(false);
        c.setEnabled(false);
        b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        c.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}

    } else if (randomNum == 1) {
        if (sSubCadena.equals(respuestacorrecta)) {

            b.setEnabled(false);
            d.setEnabled(false);
            b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            d.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else if ((pSubCadena.equals(respuestacorrecta)) || (tSubCadena.equals(respuestacorrecta))) {

            a.setEnabled(false);
            d.setEnabled(false);
            a.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            d.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else if (rSubCadena.equals(respuestacorrecta)){
            a.setEnabled(false);
            c.setEnabled(false);
            a.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
    } else if (randomNum == 2) {
        if (sSubCadena.equals(respuestacorrecta)) {

            b.setEnabled(false);
            c.setEnabled(false);
            b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else if (pSubCadena.equals(respuestacorrecta)) {

            a.setEnabled(false);
            c.setEnabled(false);
            a.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else if ((tSubCadena.equals(respuestacorrecta)) || (rSubCadena.equals(respuestacorrecta))) {
            a.setEnabled(false);
            b.setEnabled(false);
            a.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
    }
 }



 public void chequearrespuesta (View view){

  Button respuestabtn = (Button)findViewById(view.getId());



    String btntexto = respuestabtn.getText().toString();
    btntexto=btntexto.substring(3);

  if(btntexto.equals(respuestacorrecta)){

    if(quizcontador==CONTADORQUIZ){
        acumulado.setText("300.000.000$");
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Has ganado el juego", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
        int contador=14  ;
        String dato=Integer.toString(contador);
        Intent i=new Intent(preguntas.this, Transicion.class);
        i.putExtra("DATO",dato);
        startActivity(i);
        avanzar(7000);
    }

   else if (quizcontador==14){
        quizcontador++;
        respuestabtn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.millonariobotonesverde)) ;
        MainActivity.tonoverde.start();
        acumulado.setText("200.000.000$");
        int contador=13  ;
        String dato=Integer.toString(contador);
        Intent i=new Intent(preguntas.this, Transicion.class);
        i.putExtra("DATO",dato);
        startActivity(i);
        avanzar(7000);


    }
    else if (quizcontador==13){
        quizcontador++;
        respuestabtn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.millonariobotonesverde)) ;
        MainActivity.tonoverde.start();
        acumulado.setText("100.000.000$");
        int contador=12  ;
        String dato=Integer.toString(contador);
        Intent i=new Intent(preguntas.this, Transicion.class);
        i.putExtra("DATO",dato);
        startActivity(i);
        avanzar(7000);


    }
    else if (quizcontador==12){
        quizcontador++;
        respuestabtn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.millonariobotonesverde)) ;
        MainActivity.tonoverde.start();
        acumulado.setText("50.000.000$");
        int contador=11  ;
        String dato=Integer.toString(contador);
        Intent i=new Intent(preguntas.this, Transicion.class);
        i.putExtra("DATO",dato);
        startActivity(i);
        avanzar(7000);


    }
    else if (quizcontador==11){
        quizcontador++;
        respuestabtn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.millonariobotonesverde)) ;
        MainActivity.tonoverde.start();
        acumulado.setText("20.000.000$");
        int contador=10  ;
        String dato=Integer.toString(contador);
        Intent i=new Intent(preguntas.this, Transicion.class);
        i.putExtra("DATO",dato);
        startActivity(i);
        avanzar(7000);

    }
    else if (quizcontador==10){
        quizcontador++;
        respuestabtn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.millonariobotonesverde)) ;
        MainActivity.tonoverde.start();
        acumulado.setText("15.000.000$");
        int contador=9  ;
        String dato=Integer.toString(contador);
        Intent i=new Intent(preguntas.this, Transicion.class);
        i.putExtra("DATO",dato);
        startActivity(i);
        avanzar(7000);

    }
    else if (quizcontador==9){
        quizcontador++;
        respuestabtn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.millonariobotonesverde)) ;
        MainActivity.tonoverde.start();
        acumulado.setText("10.000.000$");
        int contador=8  ;
        String dato=Integer.toString(contador);
        Intent i=new Intent(preguntas.this, Transicion.class);
        i.putExtra("DATO",dato);
        startActivity(i);
        avanzar(7000);

    }
    else if (quizcontador==8){
        quizcontador++;
        respuestabtn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.millonariobotonesverde)) ;
        MainActivity.tonoverde.start();
        acumulado.setText("7.000.000$");
        int contador=7  ;
        String dato=Integer.toString(contador);
        Intent i=new Intent(preguntas.this, Transicion.class);
        i.putExtra("DATO",dato);
        startActivity(i);
        avanzar(7000);


    }
    else if (quizcontador==7){
        quizcontador++;
        respuestabtn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.millonariobotonesverde)) ;
        MainActivity.tonoverde.start();
        acumulado.setText("5.000.000$");
        int contador=6  ;
        String dato=Integer.toString(contador);
        Intent i=new Intent(preguntas.this, Transicion.class);
        i.putExtra("DATO",dato);
        startActivity(i);
        avanzar(7000);


    }
    else if (quizcontador==6){
        quizcontador++;
        respuestabtn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.millonariobotonesverde)) ;
        MainActivity.tonoverde.start();
        acumulado.setText("3.000.000$");;
        int contador=5  ;
        String dato=Integer.toString(contador);
        Intent i=new Intent(preguntas.this, Transicion.class);
        i.putExtra("DATO",dato);
        startActivity(i);
        avanzar(7000);

    }
    else if (quizcontador==5){
        quizcontador++;
        respuestabtn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.millonariobotonesverde)) ;
        MainActivity.tonoverde.start();
        acumulado.setText("1.500.000$");
        int contador=4  ;
        String dato=Integer.toString(contador);
        Intent i=new Intent(preguntas.this, Transicion.class);
        i.putExtra("DATO",dato);
        startActivity(i);
        avanzar(7000);



    }
    else if (quizcontador==4){
        quizcontador++;
        respuestabtn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.millonariobotonesverde)) ;
        MainActivity.tonoverde.start();
        acumulado.setText("1.000.000$");
        int contador=3  ;
        String dato=Integer.toString(contador);
        Intent i=new Intent(preguntas.this, Transicion.class);
        i.putExtra("DATO",dato);
        startActivity(i);
        avanzar(7000);



    }
    else if (quizcontador==3){
        quizcontador++;
        respuestabtn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.millonariobotonesverde)) ;
        MainActivity.tonoverde.start();
        acumulado.setText("500.000$");
        int contador=2  ;
        String dato=Integer.toString(contador);
        Intent i=new Intent(preguntas.this, Transicion.class);
        i.putExtra("DATO",dato);
        startActivity(i);
        avanzar(7000);



    }
    else if (quizcontador==2){
        quizcontador++;
        respuestabtn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.millonariobotonesverde)) ;
        MainActivity.tonoverde.start();
        acumulado.setText("200.000$");
        int contador=1;
        avanzar(4000);




    }
    else if (quizcontador==1){
        quizcontador++;
        acumulado.setText("100.000$");
        respuestabtn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.millonariobotonesverde)) ;
        MainActivity.tonoverde.start();
        int contador=0;
        avanzar(4000);
    }




}else {

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Has perdido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
    MainActivity.tonorojo.start();
    respuestabtn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.millonariobotonesrojo)) ;
  }

}

@Override
protected  void onPause(){

    super.onPause();

    MainActivity.preguntas915.pause();

}
@Override
protected void onResume(){

    super.onResume();


    MainActivity.preguntas915.start();


}
@Override
protected void onDestroy(){

    super.onDestroy();
    if (MainActivity.preguntas915.isPlaying()){
        MainActivity.preguntas915.stop();
        MainActivity.preguntas915.release();}

}
}
```

y la siguiente clase transicion:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Transicion extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView  micontador,uno,dos,tres,cuatro,cinco,seis,siete,ocho,nueve,diez,once,doce,trece,catorce,quince;
int contador;
Button continuar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_transicion);
    MainActivity.preguntas915.start();
    continuar=(Button) findViewById(R.id.continuar);
    continuar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (contador==15){
                String dato=preguntas.acumulado.getText().toString();
                Intent i=new Intent(Transicion.this, acumuladoganado.class);
                i.putExtra("DATO",dato);
                startActivity(i);
            }else if(contador==0) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"contador=0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
                preguntas preguntas=new preguntas();
                preguntas.showNextQuiz();
            }
            else if (contador==1){
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"contador=1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
                preguntas preguntas=new preguntas();
                preguntas.showNextQuiz();
            }
        }
    });
    Intent intent =getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras!=null){

        String dato=extras.getString("DATO");
        contador=Integer.parseInt(dato);
        contador++;
    }
    uno=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.uno);
    dos=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dos);
    tres=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tres);
    cuatro=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cuatro);
    cinco=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cinco);
    seis=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.seis);
    siete=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.siete);
    ocho=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ocho);
    nueve=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.nueve);
    diez=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.diez);
    once=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.once);
    doce=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.doce);
    trece=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.trece);
    catorce=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.catorce);
    quince=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.quince);




    if (contador==1){
        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
        gd.setColor(Color.parseColor("#fff17a0a"));
        gd.setCornerRadius(6);
        gd.setStroke(6, 0xFF000000);
        uno.setPadding(3,3,3,3);
        uno.setBackground(gd);
    }else if (contador==2) {
        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
        gd.setColor(Color.parseColor("#fff17a0a"));
        gd.setCornerRadius(6);
        gd.setStroke(6, 0xFF000000);
        dos.setPadding(3,3,3,3);
        dos.setBackground(gd);
    }else if (contador==3){
        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
        gd.setColor(Color.parseColor("#fff17a0a"));
        gd.setCornerRadius(6);
        gd.setStroke(6, 0xFF000000);
        tres.setPadding(3,3,3,3);
        tres.setBackground(gd);
    }else if (contador==4){
        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
        gd.setColor(Color.parseColor("#fff17a0a"));
        gd.setCornerRadius(6);
        gd.setStroke(6, 0xFF000000);
        cuatro.setPadding(3,3,3,3);
        cuatro.setBackground(gd);
    }else if (contador==5){
        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
        gd.setColor(Color.parseColor("#fff17a0a"));
        gd.setCornerRadius(6);
        gd.setStroke(6, 0xFF000000);
        cinco.setPadding(3,3,3,3);
        cinco.setBackground(gd);
    }else if (contador==6){
        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
        gd.setColor(Color.parseColor("#fff17a0a"));
        gd.setCornerRadius(6);
        gd.setStroke(6, 0xFF000000);
        seis.setPadding(3,3,3,3);
        seis.setBackground(gd);
    }else if (contador==7){
        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
        gd.setColor(Color.parseColor("#fff17a0a"));
        gd.setCornerRadius(6);
        gd.setStroke(6, 0xFF000000);
        siete.setPadding(3,3,3,3);
        siete.setBackground(gd);
    }else if (contador==8){
        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
        gd.setColor(Color.parseColor("#fff17a0a"));
        gd.setCornerRadius(6);
        gd.setStroke(6, 0xFF000000);
        ocho.setPadding(3,3,3,3);
        ocho.setBackground(gd);
    }else if (contador==9){
        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
        gd.setColor(Color.parseColor("#fff17a0a"));
        gd.setCornerRadius(6);
        gd.setStroke(6, 0xFF000000);
        nueve.setPadding(3,3,3,3);
        nueve.setBackground(gd);
    }else if (contador==10){
        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
        gd.setColor(Color.parseColor("#fff17a0a"));
        gd.setCornerRadius(6);
        gd.setStroke(6, 0xFF000000);
        diez.setPadding(3,3,3,3);
        diez.setBackground(gd);
    }else if (contador==11){
        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
        gd.setColor(Color.parseColor("#fff17a0a"));
        gd.setCornerRadius(6);
        gd.setStroke(6, 0xFF000000);
        once.setPadding(3,3,3,3);
        once.setBackground(gd);
    }else if (contador==12){
        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
        gd.setColor(Color.parseColor("#fff17a0a"));
        gd.setCornerRadius(6);
        gd.setStroke(6, 0xFF000000);
        doce.setPadding(3,3,3,3);
        doce.setBackground(gd);
    }else if (contador==13){
        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
        gd.setColor(Color.parseColor("#fff17a0a"));
        gd.setCornerRadius(6);
        gd.setStroke(6, 0xFF000000);
        trece.setPadding(3,3,3,3);
        trece.setBackground(gd);
    }else if (contador==14){
        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
        gd.setColor(Color.parseColor("#fff17a0a"));
        gd.setCornerRadius(6);
        gd.setStroke(6, 0xFF000000);
        catorce.setPadding(3,3,3,3);
        catorce.setBackground(gd);
    }
}
```

}

quiero llamar el metodo shownextquiz con el boton continuar de la clase transicion pero no me funciona, alguien sabe porque?

Comment: te marca error?

Comment: NO, no funciona , y le puse un intent para que regresara a preguntas y tampoco

Comment: preguntas Clase = new preguntas.shownextquiz();

Comment: te recomiendo que tu pregunta muestre el código que estas realizando pero que indiques que se supone debe realizar. @JohanBerrio

Comment: Hola @JohanBerrio, pudiste ?,cual es la solución